# Creating a multiple query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I would like to run 2 queries within the same code, but I cannot figure out how to. The 2 queries are as follows:

```
UPDATE usercomp
         SET shiftstart = shifts.shiftstarttime,
             shiftfinish = shifts.shiftfinishtime
FROM shifts
     WHERE usercomp.shiftid = shifts.id
         SET break1start = breaks.timestarted,
             break1finish = breaks.timefinished,
             break1duration = breaks.duration
FROM breaks
     WHERE usercomp.break1id = breaks.id;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SET"
LINE 6: SET break1start = breaks.timestarted,
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Are you trying to update two tables in a single statement?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: what this is doing is like a vlookup in the shiftidcolumn in user comp there is a number ie 1 it looks up in shifts for 1 in the id column then populates the data in shiftstarttime&shiftfinishtime into the shiftstart & shiftfinish columns in usercomp. The break one does the same , but off the breaks table. Both queries work fine separately, but would like them to run together.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: user comp : Shift   Shift Id : 1   shifts : |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write two `UPDATE` statement

```
UPDATE usercomp 
    SET shiftstart = shifts.shiftstarttime,
        shiftfinish = shifts.shiftfinishtime
FROM shifts
WHERE usercomp.shiftid = shifts.id;

UPDATE usercomp
    SET break1start = breaks.timestarted,
        break1finish = breaks.timefinished,
        break1duration = breaks.duration
FROM breaks
WHERE usercomp.break1id = breaks.id;
```